# no file is uploading to my hosting. what's wrong with my php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, file-upload

this is the problem. I bought an hosting. i'm trying to set up an CMS in my website.. what happening is none of my files are uploading to webserver through script..

i'm able to upload it via FTP.

but if i go to WP cms and upload an media or plugin to server it shows "missing a temporary folder"...
i tried with Magento & Prestashop.. both installs but unable to upload product images, files, or anything through them..

is it due to wrong configuration of php.ini file.??

kindly check my php.ini file below:

http://popstores.in/phpinfo.php

kindly help me with the problem. bcoz i'm unable to do any works..

Any information or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: based on the error message you're reporting, try setting `upload_tmp_dir`, [although it should fallback to your system's tmp dir if you don't specify one](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

Answer (score 0):

chmod the upload folder to the approp permissions? You can google screen shots and you may want to start with 777 on that folder although that setting is not safe but to test.  Check the server error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to set your upload_tmp_dir to something like /tmp
Also note that your current settings list post_max_size = 8M while your upload_max_filesize = 12M , so your files can't go beyond 8M

Comment: actually i'm trying to upload an 20KB file only. but none of my files are uploading. i changed max file size to 200M now.